# Is it possible to reverse flexbox cross axis direction?

Tags: css, flexbox

We can specify the direction of the main axis with `flex-direction` property. But, from what I found, there is no property that would do the same for the cross axis.

It means that the only possible combinations are the following:
(main axis is bold, cross axis is thin)
[image: flexbox axis directions]

Is there any way to apply the other 4 possible arrangements?
[image]

**EDIT:** assume that `flex-wrap` is set to `wrap`, so there are multiple rows or columns on the cross axis

**EDIT2:** thanks vals! setting `flex-wrap` to `wrap-reverse` does reverse the direction of the cross axis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [wrap-reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) value allows for this:

> The flex-wrap property controls whether the flex container is
> single-line or multi-line, and the direction of the cross-axis, which
> determines the direction new lines are stacked in.
>
> nowrap The flex container is single-line.
>
> wrap The flex container is multi-line.
>
> **wrap-reverse** Same as wrap.
>
> For the values that are not wrap-reverse, the cross-start direction is
> equivalent to either the inline-start or block-start direction of the
> current writing mode (whichever is in the cross axis) and the
> cross-end direction is the opposite direction of cross-start. **When
> flex-wrap is wrap-reverse, the cross-start and cross-end directions
> are swapped.**

[w3c source](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-wrap-property)

Comment: How this answer can be correct if the question assume that `flex-wrap` is set to `wrap`? If we suppose that flex-wrap should be wrap, it can't be swapped to wrap-reverse. So the answer is not correct, or the question is not clear.

Comment: @MattiaAstorino Clearly, the OP doesn't know about wrap. So, what he is saying is "I am wrapping the content". Also, from the docs, "wrap-reverse" = same as wrap. And also, this answer is marked as accepted, so for the OP at least it's ok.